# $T$ , a linear functional is a linear combination of $T_{i}$'s under some relation.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand a proof of the following problem :

Let $T , T_{1}, T_{2},\ldots , T_{n}$ be linear functionals on a normed linear space $X$ such that $\cap_{i=1}^{n} \ker(T_{i}) \subset \ker(T)$. Prove that $T$ can be written as a linear combination of $T_{i}$'s, that is , there exists $c_{1},c_{2},\ldots,c_{n}$ such that

$$T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}T_{i}$$

Proof: For simplicity let $X$ is a normed space on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let us define the following map: 
$$\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$

$$\phi(x)=(T(x),T_{1}(x),\ldots, T_{n}(x))$$

Clear $\phi$ is a linear map. Observe that $\phi$  is not onto! This is because $(1,0,0,\ldots, 0) \notin Range(\phi)$. This is because $T_{1}(x)=T_{2}(x)=\ldots=T_{n}(x)=0$ $\implies T=0$.Hence $Range(\phi)$ is a proper subspace which is finite dimensional and hence it is closed! Upto this it's all fine. Then the author writes the following:

By Hahn-Banach theorem, We will get a functional on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that is, scalars $d, d_{1},d_{2},\ldots d_{n}$ such that

$$dT(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}T_{i}(x)=0 \hspace{2 cm} \forall x\in X; d\neq 0$$.
Now our desired scalars $c_{i}=\frac{d_{i}}{d}$.

Now what I don't understand is how is the Hahn-Banach theorem being used here. I suppose that some corollary is being used here. Since the author has shown $Range(\phi)$ is proper closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ has some significance. A corollary that quickly comes into mind is that :

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space and $Y$ a proper closed space. Let $x\in X-Y$, then $d(x,Y)=d >0$. Then there exists a linear functional on X such that $f(x)=d$, $||f||=1$ and $f(y)=0 \forall y \in Y$.

Is this the corollary that is being used here! Even if this is used how has the author used this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corollary that you are stated can be used for that step.

Apply the corollary for
$
 X= \mathbb R^{n+1}
$
and
$
 Y= \operatorname{Range}(\phi),
$
and for $x$ we chose the vector $(1,0,\dots,0) \in X\setminus Y$.

Then your corollary states that there is a functional $f$ that is zero on $\operatorname{Range}(\phi)$ but $f(1,0,\dots,0)\neq0$.
Since functionals on finite dimensional spaces are vectors,
we can write $(d,d_1,\dots,d_n)$ for $f$.
Note that $d\neq 0$.

Then
$$dT(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}T_{i}(x)=0 \hspace{2 cm} \forall x\in X; d\neq 0$$
follows (using $\operatorname{Range}(\phi)$).